# Notation for the "k" largest elements of array

Tags: sequences-and-series, notation, maxima-minima

**Introduction.** Given a set, or a vector, or a sequence $A$ with components:
\begin{equation}
A = \{a_1, a_2, a_3, \ldots, a_n \}
\end{equation}
we can indicate the maximum of $A$ as $\max(A)$, or as $\max(\{a_1, a_2, a_3, \ldots, a_n \})$.

**Question.** Is there any specific notation to indicate the "k" top maxima (i.e. the "k" largest values)? I mean, if we sort an array in a descending order, i.e. from the largest to the smallest values, is there a notation to say "we consider the "k" top largest values"?

**Note.** I would like to mathematically (and correctly) write what some programming languages do, such as, for example, the [Matlab "maxk" function](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/maxk.html).

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.

Comment: Mathematics isn't as strict a language as programming. It is much more important to communicate clearly than adhere to some general formality. I have never seen shorthand notation for the $k$'th largest element, so I would always write it out in words, like you did. If you really need something formal, it would be like "$a$ such that $\exists ! b_1,\dots,b_{k-1}\in A\forall i: \: a<b_i$. The uniqueness guarantees $k$'th maximality.

Comment: Thanks a lot @SomeCallMeTim! ....however, I think I do not understand exactly what you wrote with the quantifiers... I mean, my interpretation for this part "$a \;\text{such that} \; \exists ! \; b_1, \ldots, b_{k-1} \in A$" is:
"an element $a$ such that $b_1, \ldots, b_{k-1}$ exist and belong to the set or array $A$".
My interpretation for this part "$\forall i \; \colon \; a<b_{i}$" is:
"for each $i$, the element $a$ is less than all the elements $b_{i}$"

Comment: Yes, but $!$ indicates uniqueness. This is why I am telling you to use words instead of "formal" math. The statement should be understood as: there exists a unique collection of $k-1$ elements of $A$ that are larger than $a$. This ensures that $a$ is at most the $k$'th largest, and uniqueness of this collection ensures that it cannot be smaller than the $k$'th largest.

Comment: **Part 1.** Thanks @SomeCallMeTim, this is now clearer :-) I was trying to understand better with an example. Let's consider $A=\{a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4, a_5\}$. If we sort it in a descending order, we get, for example, $A_{sort}=\{a_3, a_5, a_2, a_1, a_4\}$, where $a_3$ is the largest value, $a_5$ is the second largest value, and so on. Now, we want to know the $3$ largest values, i.e. $k=3$. That means, we want to know $a_3, a_5, a_2$.

Comment: **Part 2.** With your definition, "there exists a unique collection of $k-1$ elements of $A$", it means we have $k-1=2$ elements of the unique collection, i.e. $b_1$ and $b_2$, that would correspond to $a_3$ and $a_5$ (right?). Still with your definition, as far as I understood, the index $i$ would refer to the unique collection formed by $b_1$ and $b_2$, i.e. it would take the values $i=1$ for $b_1$ and $i=2$ for $b_2$.

Comment: **Part 3.** Therefore, $\forall i, \; a<b_i$, would mean that 
$\{a_2, a_1, a_4\}<\left(\{b_1,b_2\}=\{a_3,a_5\}\right)$, i.e. that all the elements $\{a_2, a_1, a_4\}$ would satisfy this property, and not just $a_2$. So, yes $\{b_1,b_2\}=\{a_3,a_5\}$ are larger than $\{a_2, a_1, a_4\}$, but, as far as I understood, each of $a_2, a_1, a_4$ could be the $k^{th}-$largest value, and not only $a_2$. Also, if I understood correctly the "unique collection" tell us that I cannot have other collection of $b_i$ values, i.e. other permutations of the set formed by $b_i$ elements.

Comment: **Part 4.** I am a bit confused, I am sorry, but I like your way :-) Many thanks for your comments :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the concept of sorting, and address the $(n-k+1)$ element:

Let A be a sorted sequence of numbers, denoted by

$A = \{a_1, a_2, a_3, \ldots, a_n\}$

such that  $ a_i<a_j$  for all $i<j$

If you cannot define $A$ as a sorted sequence, then define another sequence $SA$ which is a sorted sequence of the elements of $A$. This can be done using the following definition:

$SA = \text{sort}(A)$

The $k^{th}$ largest element is $SA_{n-k+1}$, or if $A$ is sorted, then his $k^{th}$ largest element is $A_{n-k+1}$

Comment: thanks a lot @tutizeri! :-) I would accept both your and Marco Ripà's answers, they are both nice! :-) But I do not know if I can accept both

Comment: @Ommo Now that I think about it, maybe it would be clearer to define the sort in descending order, like Marco Ripà did, such that the $k^{th}$ largest element is $SA_k$, which is easier to read.

Answer (score 2):

I would simply write something as follows.

Let $A = \{a_1, a_2, a_3, \ldots, a_n \}$, where $a_1 > a_2 > \cdots > a_n$.
Now, assume $k < n$ so that we define $\max_{k}:=\{a_1, a_2, \dots, a_k\}$
(i.e., $\max_{k} \subset A$ since $A - \max_{k} = \{a_{k+1}, a_{k+2}, \dots, a_{n-1}, a_{n}\}$).

I think it should work fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Marco Ripà!

Comment: You are welcome!